# Vue-router not working when deployed

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm having this problem where vue-router doesn't work when i deployed it to production. I narrowed the problem down to possibly the history mode from  vue-router.

link https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

The link above says that i have to edit the server configuration in order to fix this. I'm using vue-loader and can't figure out where i have to place the code in order to fix the error described within the article.

Comment: it is the **server** configuration. what server do you use for deployment? Apache, Nginx, Node.JS, …? And then modify the corresponding config.

Comment: I'm just hosting it on azure. Dont know what server is used :(